# How to set an distanceFilter to the flutter location receiving data

Tags: android, flutter, location

I'm trying to set a change settings function to my getLocation() with no lucky. My current locantion it's been updated despite I move or not, what cause noise in my variable. I'm probably defined my change settings function wrongly, and if use the function provided by the docmentation page says the LocationAccuracy isn't defined.

```
 void getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      Uint8List imageData = await getMarker();
      var location = await _locationTracker.getLocation();

      if (_locationSubscription != null) {
        _locationSubscription.cancel();
      }

      updateMarkerAndCircle(location, imageData);
      location.changeSettings(interval: 3000, distanceFilter: 10.0);
      _locationSubscription =
          _locationTracker.onLocationChanged().listen((newLocalData) {
        if (_controller != null) {
          _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              new CameraPosition(
                  bearing: 192.8334901395799,
                  target: LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
                  tilt: 0,
                  zoom: 18.00)));
          updateMarkerAndCircle(newLocalData, imageData);
        }

        routesCoordinates.currentLocation =
            LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude);

        if (routesCoordinates.inCourse) {
          routesCoordinates.upDateCurrentLocation();
          routesCoordinates.latlngSendBackEnd.add({
            "lat_lng": LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
            "date": DateTime.now().toString(),
          });
          drawPolyLine.latlng
              .add(LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude));
          drawPolyLine.drawPolyLine();
        }
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        debugPrint("Permission Denied");
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help, advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved, the sintaxe on the docmentation was wrong.

```
      Future<bool> changeSettings({
        LocationAccuracy accuracy = LocationAccuracy.HIGH,
        int interval = 1000,
        double distanceFilter = 5,
      }) {
        return _locationTracker.changeSettings(
          accuracy: accuracy,
          interval: interval,
          distanceFilter: distanceFilter,
        );
      }
```

LocationAccuracy accuracy = LocationAccuracy.HIGH,

The "high" MUST be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try word **await** before **changeSettings** command

```
await location.changeSettings(interval: 3000, distanceFilter: 10.0);
```